# mapbox- take location from user by drag marker, node.js

Tags: html, node.js, forms, mapbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Create a draggable Marker</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>


<div id="map"></div>
<pre id="coordinates" class="coordinates"></pre>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mytkn';
    var coordinates = document.getElementById('coordinates');
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    });

    var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
        draggable: true
    })
        .setLngLat([0, 0])
        .addTo(map);

    function onDragEnd() {
        var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
        coordinates.style.display = 'block';
        coordinates.innerHTML =
            'Longitude: ' + lngLat.lng + '<br />Latitude: ' + lngLat.lat;
    }

    marker.on('dragend', onDragEnd);
</script>

<div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="lat">
        <input type="text" name="long">
        
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

So I have part of code that makes draggable markers, so I can get users lat and long. Now I want that data in form so I can pass it to node.js backend (into database). How can I save that (pass) coordinates to form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about calling your node.js backend's API endpoint by using [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in `onDragEnd`?